# Viewing a site using Chrome developer tools to simulate an iPhone 12 looks different than viewing the site on an actual iPhone 12. Why is this?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, padding, margin, browserstack

Sections of my site look a little different on Chrome Dev Tools simulating an iPhone 12 than an actual iPhone 12. Why is this? I've signed up for browserstack. Do you guys think they produce an accurate representation of a site on different devices? Do you recommend any others?

This is the site (iPhone 12) on Chrome Dev:  https://snipboard.io/OpU8aj.jpg

Same site on my iPhone 12: https://snipboard.io/vl6b8f.jpg

Notice the type in relation to the red background?

I'm wondering too... This is the first time I've used %'s for my padding and margins. I usually use em, rem or px. Could using percentages have something to do with it? I do understand the the percentage is based on the parent element. But still... not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Thank you

Comment: I just purchased Browserstack live. Great tool. Clears up my issue. I can run tests with them as they do not use simulators. You are looking at your site on a real device. Perfect! I will be using Browserstack instead of Google or Firefox dev tools from now on.

Comment: Hey Karl, I'm sorry to hear that you felt this way, caused by my comment. I didn't mean to condescend on you the slightest; I just felt your expectation that mobile iPhone (or any other mobile device in the list) in Chrome dev tools being *emulated* is so far off that it would be obvious to anyone thinking about it for 2 seconds that it's neither in Chrome's scope, capacity nor capability to emulate devices and their native software. On top of that, your own answer to me felt like you are trying to *advertise* the product you mentioned.

Comment: No worries and thanks for the reply. Ya, I thought it might be taken that way, that maybe you guys thought I was advertising the product. I'm sure everyone knows about browserstack. I simply thought if someone didn't, it might be a useful tool for them. I was trying to help. I try to word my questions in a way that make sense but sometimes I'm not sure how to ask it. I'll work on my communication. I don't have the knowledge and skill set most of you have. I went to college for design, before computers. Pretty much self taught. I study on training sites to get up to speed. Still learning...

Comment: @Karl did you find out the exact cause of the difference? If yes, please post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I learned, and I'm sure most of you know this, any iPhone above an iPhone 8, that Apple's documented viewport size is not the actual pixel size (w x h) that displays a website or app. I discovered this after researching Apple dev docs. There is now a "safe area" leaving room for native device buttons on the top and bottom in portrait mode, or both sides in landscape mode. You subtract the area for these buttons from the manufactures documented viewport size to get the real displayed viewport or "safe area". Of course it will be different for every device.

I hope i'm not breaking any rules with the following. I used "what is my viewport" https://whatismyviewport.com/ Pull up this url in any device and it will show the actual width by height in px, of that device. This is the actual size your website or app will be displayed at.

I am now able to set new media queries using the above info instead of media queries based on the device manufacturer's documented viewport size. This solved the issues I was having.